# Why my new CSS code is not loading anymore in my test environment?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, asset-pipeline

I work on a Rails app with Rspec & Capybara in my test environment.

For few days now, any changes I apply to my CSS is not anymore compiled when I launch my tests. The former CSS is well compiled but not the new one. No problem to load the new JS.

I don't really know where I should look at to solve my problem...

Comment: Do you use any version management system (e.g. git)? You could check out some other version and try to find the first commit when the problem first appeared (search for "how to git bisect" tutorials).

Comment: @raphael-allard - if you are still having issue then try `bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile`. It cleans and re-compile assets.